# Office-addin review comments

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, appsource

Got below review comments from Microsoft team

**General Content** 
**1100.1.3  Additional Charge Disclosures**

Offer descriptions must notify users in the description of any extra charges to use advertised features or to activate additional features or content. Please update the description of the offer to include such information and re-submit your offer.

**General Content 
1100.1.4  Additional Service or Account Disclosures**

•   Your offer depends upon additional services or accounts for full functionality but does not disclose these dependencies in the description. Please update the description and re-submit your offer.

•   Your offer contains features which are unlocked through the purchase of a license or additional services. If your product offers in-app purchases, you must select the "My product requires purchase of a service or offers additional in-app purchases" check box when submitting your offer via Partner Center. Please update your offer as required and resubmit.

**Offer Information and Support Contacts 
100.5.1.4  Terms of Use**

All links must lead to appropriate and expected information. Please update the Terms of Use link(s) and re-submit your offer. The expected information was: Terms of use policies for your offer.

**Could anyone help me to understand**

**1. where to add 1100.1.3 (Additional Charge Disclosures) as my product is free of cost for now?**

**2. where to add 1100.1.4 (Additional Service or Account Disclosures ) as I've already added this information in description box under marketplace listing?**

**3. where to add Terms of Use as I didn't see any specific area?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This information should be entered in the description field on the marketplacelisting tab if any payment is required at any point to use the add-in.
2. This information should be entered in the description field on the marketplacelisting tab.
3. This should be entered in the 'End User License Agreement (EULA) link' field at the bottom of the page on the properties tab.